# File increasing in size after deleting content

Tags: text-editors, editing, text-editing

I recently cleaned up some .PHP files of mine with alot of code in them, there was alot of stuff that was not needed so I deleted those lines, in one case it was around 200 lines of code.

The strange thing that occured is, after re-saving that one .PHP file, the size went from 70,3 kb to 72,5 kb.

How is that possible ?

Comment: It would help if we knew which editor and which OS.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your editor automatically expanded tabs into spaces? This could easily account for few extra KB of size, even if some lines were deleted.

In addition to that, your editor could have converted Linux line endings `CR` into Windows style `CR+LF`.

If you have your files under source control, you should be able to easily tell what happened using commands like `git diff HEAD~` or `svn diff -r PREV file.php`.